# Phing Failtask if Esc is pressed . It's possible ?

Tags: key, task, phing

I've got a  Phing buildfile with some tasks.
Problem is I don't have one way to quit de script if something goes wrong, right now, my only possibility is to close cmd and open cmd again.
What I want is abort the execution of the task by pressing "esc".
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't kill a Phing build script while it's running, because it might leave things in a bad state. Instead the script should check for an indicator to quit at key points in the script.

You can create a temp file at the start of the script. During execution check that the file still exists, and if it has been deleted by the user abort the build script.

At the start of your script create a temp file.

```
    <touch file="delete.me"/>
```

Then at different points in your script check that it still exists.

```
    <if><not><available file="delete.me"/></not><then><fail message="User aborted build script." /></then></if>
```

You can now abort a script at anytime by deleting the `delete.me` file.

Alternatively, you can prompt for a user to continue the script using the [InputTask](http://www.phing.info/docs/stable/webhelp/InputTask.html).

```
    <input propertyName="cont" defaultValue="n" promptChar="?" validArgs="y,n">Continue</input>
    <if><equals arg1="${cont}" arg2="n"/><then><fail message="User aborted build script."/></then></if>
```

The above will block execution of the script until a user presses `Y` to continue.

If you're performing file operations or SQL commands that take a long time to execute, then it's best to let them finish first before aborting the script. Pressing `ctrl+c` should only be done if you suspect the script is doing something wrong.